# Can I listen to rotation and position changes on gltf meshes created by gltf animation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a .glb object that performs keyframes animation.
I have imported this object to my Three JS scene and everything works fine.
But I need the mesh rotation and position changes that happen from animation.
Anyway, they the properties are changing while the animation is being played (and they're moving).
Here's my code:

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from "@react-three/drei";

export default forwardRef(({ ...props }, plane) => {

  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF("/plane.glb");
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, plane);

  const topR = useRef();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (plane.current !== null) {
      const { fold } = actions;
      fold.repetitions = 1;
      fold.clampWhenFinished = true;
      fold.play();
    }
  }, [topR.current]);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (actions.fold.isRunning()) {
      if (topR.current) {
        console.log(topR.current.rotation);
        console.log(topR.current.position);
        //THEY DO NOT CHANGE FROM THE ANIMATION
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <group
      layers={2}
      scale={[8, 8, 8]}
      ref={plane}
      {...props}
      dispose={null}
    >
      <mesh
        name="topR"
        ref={topR}
        layers={2}
        geometry={nodes.topR.geometry}
        material={nodes.topR.material}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.topR.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.topR.morphTargetInfluences}
      >
        <meshStandardMaterial
          {...materials}
          metalness={0}
          roughness={0.8}
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
          shadowSide={THREE.DoubleSide}
        />
      </mesh>
      <mesh
    </group>
  );
});

useGLTF.preload("/plane.glb");
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
    if (topR.current) {
    console.log(topR.current.camera.rotation);
    console.log(topR.current.camera.position);
    console.log(topR.current);
    }
```

inspect `topR.current` you can see what is changing and all that.